# TypeError _______________ is not a function when modifying JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object, typeerror

So I have some existing Javascript I'm working with. This is the existing JSON that is working (modified and simplified to keep things manageable):

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "11",
        "type": "subType",
        "attributesList": {
            "atribute1": "1",
            "atribute2": "2"
        },
        "description": {
            "d1": "lorem ipsum",
            "d2": {
                "lorem ipsum 1": "li1 content",
                "lorem ipsum 2": "li2 content"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

One of the operations against this existing JSON is adding a new 'item' which looks like this:

```
{
"id": "12",
"type": "subType",
"attributesList": {
    "atribute1": "1",
    "atribute2": "2"
},
"description": {
    "d1": "lorem ipsum",
    "d2": {
        "lorem ipsum 1": "li1 content",
        "lorem ipsum 2": "li2 content"
    }
}
}
```

The code executing all this is incredibly lengthy, but this is the line that performs the operation:

```
that.product.addItem(item.toObject());
```

So, this works fine. However we have another JSON format that needs to be modified in the same way. The new format is:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "someType",
        "name": "item name",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "11",
                "type": "subType",
                "attributesList": {
                    "atribute1": "1 attr",
                    "atribute2": "2 attr"
                },
                "description": {
                    "d1": "lorem ipsum",
                    "d2": {
                        "lorem ipsum1": "li1 content",
                        "lorem ipsum 2": "li2 content"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "type": "subType",
                "attributesList": {
                    "atribute1": "1 attr",
                    "atribute2": "2 attr"
                },
                "description": {
                    "d1": "lorem ipsum",
                    "d2": {
                        "lorem ipsum1": "li1 content",
                        "lorem ipsum 2": "li2 content"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "quantity": 1
    }
]
}
```

As you can see the subTypes are now nested under a parent type. So my thought is, to add an item to this new format I should be able to do something like (since there is only ever one parent):

```
that.product.items[0].items.addItem(item.toObject());
```

However when I attempt to do this I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: that.product.items[0].items.addItem is not a function
```

When I get typeof on both, they both return 'object', but clearly I'm missing something. I'm pretty new to manipulating JSON like this so I'm stumped. I went down a couple paths of conversion and trying to figure this out and I'm just stuck. Hoping someone can help me out.

Comment: I'm not sure what `addItem` is since I never saw this method. But if you just want to append to an array, you should be able to use the `push()` method instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript arrays do not have an `addItem` method. Try using `push()` instead:

```
that.product.items[0].items.push(item.toObject());
```

Assuming that everything else works, that will add the result of `item.toObject()` to the end of the array `that.product.items[0].items`.

Comment: Thank you. I swear I tried that or more likely tried it when I was too deep in the weeds and it didn't work with what I had at that point. I will say now that it does work some other .get() statements are failing. I assume for similar reasons. Changing that.product.getSomeProperty(); to that.product.someProperty resolves it and appears to work for both JSON versions.